# Xamarin app crashes on android when using CollectionView

Tags: c#, xamarin

im trying to use CollectionView (Horizontal Orientation) which gets the data as observable from firebase database

its working perfectly on ios, but when im trying to run the application on android (tried 2 different devices) the app crashes 90% of the times (always crashes when i update the list)

i get this Eception: [Exception Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO9SC.jpg)

Xaml code:

```
<Frame Padding="0" x:Name="_roomMayLike" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="White" HasShadow="False">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="Rooms we think you will like:" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="14" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding RoomList}" x:Name="_lstx" SelectionMode="Single" Grid.Row="1" >

                                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                                    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

                                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>

                                            <Grid Padding="10">
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Frame HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" BackgroundColor="Green" HasShadow="true"/>
                                                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
                                                    <Label  Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="12" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                                    <Label  Text="{Binding RoomManager, StringFormat='By:{0}' }"  FontSize="12" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </Grid>

                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            </CollectionView>
                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
```

c# ViewModel code:

```
 public ScrolledViewModel()
    {

        EnterNamePopup();

        RoomList = db.subRooms();

        AddRoomHandleC = new Command(() => AddRoomFunction() );

    }
```

c# FireBase Interface:

```
public ObservableCollection<Room> subRooms()
        {
            return fbClient.Child("chatApp/Rooms")
                .AsObservable<Room>()
                .AsObservableCollection<Room>();
        }
```

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9753

Comment: @Izhar let us know if the solution in the issue works for you

Comment: i dont understand what is the practical solution

Comment: Could you show the complete code for this page?And you could try to use local static data to test.I test  your code with a set of local static data and it works.